# Android - get Date in valid format

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I use `java.sql.Date` and `SimpleDataFormat`. 
I would like get Date in format

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

like that

```
2018-06-04
```

I use

```
Date date = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String actualDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
date.valueOf(actualDate);
```

But it's not working.
What is the problem?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. `LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone).toString()` will give you the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple Try using this code instead

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse(dateString);
```

this should do the trick .

**The PROBLEM ?**
You were using different format so how would he know what you want ....

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
Date date = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String actualDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
date.valueOf(actualDate);
```

Comment: I hope this is helpful @Bartosz20188